# Explicit type is missing ('int' assumed) defining LPCSTR in global vars.

Tags: c++

I have a settings.ini file for my c++ application how ever one of my users Windows\Temp is broken resulting it is messing up for him. So I was going to move it to the users folder for him. So I wanted to make a simple script in the section for global variables as seen below. I am getting the error message "Explicit type is missing ('int' assumed)". I am new to this so could someone please help me understand what is wrong :) 
Yes I know there are better ways then using GetPrivateProfileIntA, and global vars are bad but for my purpose it works :)

```
int setloc = GetPrivateProfileIntA("C:\\Users\\loc.ini", "locdir", 0, "locdir");

LPCSTR adsf;

checkloc();

 void checkloc(){
    if (setloc == 1){
         adsf = "C:\\Users\\settings.ini";
    }
    else{
         adsf = "C:\\Windows\\Temp\\settings.ini";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The declaration `checkloc();` has no type indicated, and the compiler is assuming you mean that it returns `int` (this is allowed in C, not C++).  Simply indicate the return type as `void` to fix your problem

```
LPCSTR adsf;

void checkloc();
```

However, there's really no point in declaring a function and then immediately defining it. The definition can also serve as the declaration, so in your case your best move is to delete the line `checkloc();`

Comment: Assuming he's compiling with Visual Studio, the error message was likely something like `error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed.  Note: C++ does not support default-int`.  It seems to assume `int` so it can continue checking the code for errors, then refuse to compile because default int is non-standard.